# habarta typescript-generator : convert Java enum to Typescript string array

Tags: java, arrays, typescript, enums

I am using cz.habarta.typescript-generator in order to generate my typescript data model from my java classes and enumeration.
Here is the java enumeration I have for example:

```
public enum LineStyle {
     PLAIN, DASHED;
}
```

When converting from java, I have the following model given typescript:

```
export type LineStyle = "PLAIN" | "DASHED";
```

I would like to be able to retrieve each values of my typescript model, in an array of string. How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the configuration I needed at habarta level to generate the enumerations correctly (at least as I need them).

I added the following configuration in my pom.xml for the typescript-generator-maven-plugin pluggin:

```
<mapEnum>asEnum</mapEnum>
<nonConstEnums> true </nonConstEnums>
```

So my generated typescript models look like this:

```
export enum LineStyle {
     PLAIN = "PLAIN",
     DASHED = "DASHED",
}
```

With this declaration, I can therefore use the `Object.values` method in order to have all the values of my enumeration.

Thank you